# How do I open JSON events in Firefox console?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, console, json

I'd like to view output in my console in firefox.

Here's an example that I'd like to see: 
[image]

That's an example on Chrome. It's very easy to open the JSON object.

I can even go one level further and see this information:

[image]

Unfortunately in Firefox, this is all that it gives me:

[image: json]

Can I unfurl a json event in the console in Firefox in the same way that I can in Chrome?

Comment: Do you have an example website we can look at?

Comment: It should work with any console where you pass a json event

Answer (score 0):

Firefox also supports this. You can try it yourself:

```js
console.log("This is a log message", { title: "My Object", description: "You can inspect this object!" });
```

If it’s not working, `console.log` (or the any of the other methods) isn’t used correctly by the application. Keep in mind that this is entirely unrelated to JSON. It prints actual JavaScript objects.